Can't override the disabled Button Color
I'm feeling stupid: I can't override the color of a Button when it is disabled.
The code looks good, and I can ensure that the logic of _isDisabled is correct.
The button:
ElevatedButton(
   onPressed: _isDisabled
      ? null
      : () {
        //something really fancy
           },
   style: 
     ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
       backgroundColor: _isDisabled 
         ? Colors.amber
         : MyTheme.getCiSonoButtonColor(context: context),
       padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 50, vertical: 16
       ),
       shape: RoundedRectangleBorder( 
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
       ),
      ),
      child: Text('Button'),

As you can see I'm trying to set the color of the button (when disabled) to Amber, but the result is a light Grey. I really don't know why. It seems like there is a predefined color for the disabled mode.
How to fix this annoying problem?
For clearness I attach a screenshot of the app (look at the Grey button):

NB: when the logic turn the _isDisabled variable to false, the button looks as I want. The problem is when disabled.
(I've already tried to set the property disabledColor of ThemeData and nothing changed)

can you tell us more about  onPressed , if you can share a running a dartpad link that will be much more easier to reproduce the error. the reason being my query is because we use onPressed:  null to disable it

You can directly provide disabledBackgroundColor on styleFrom and set null on onPressed
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
    disabledBackgroundColor: Colors.amber,
  ),
  onPressed: _isDisabled ? null : () {},
  child: Text("Button"),
)


Hi! This works ... So, backgroundColor is just when the button is abled, isn't it?

yap,  ElevatedButton.styleFrom takes separate args for this
